# uib-datepicker-popup with dynamic minMode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I set the minMode of Angular Bootstrap Datepicker dynamicly?

The only way that I got it, was with the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myDate"
       uib-datepicker-popup="{{datepickerFormat}}"
       datepicker-options="{'minMode': minMode}"/>
```

In Controller

```
...
$scope.minMode='day';
```

It works well, but when the minMode change and the datepicker reopen, I have a [$compile:nonassignNon-Assignable](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=%7B%27showWeeks%27:%20false,%20%27minMode%27:%20datepickerMinMode%7D&p1=datepickerOptions&p2=uibDatepickerPopup) error in the browser console. So I would like to do something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myDate"
       uib-datepicker-popup="{{datepickerFormat}}"
       min-mode="minMode"/>
```

But unfortunately, it does not work anymore.

```
Angular version: 1.5.9
Bootstrap version: 3.3.7
angular-bootstrap version: 1.2.5
```

[See in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/324BmvEWIGS1HJxw7EsE?p=preview)

Comment: Add plunkr, that would be appreciable..

Comment: Thank you. I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not placing the `minMode` value correctly

Because you place options in your datepicker and later change these options with your buttons, you need to have that `options` object defined in your controller and refer to it in both places.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text"
        ng-model="myDate"
        is-open="showDatePicker"
        uib-datepicker-popup="mm-dd-yyyy"
        datepicker-options="options"/>
</div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.options = {'showWeeks': false, 'minMode': 'month'};
```

Now you can alter that `minMode` property using your `ng-click` expressions

```
<button ng-click="options.minMode = 'day'" class="btn">Day</button>
<button ng-click="options.minMode = 'month'" class="btn" >Month</button>
```

[Updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ytxrK0ZWrsKmhKTGWYVO?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! You help me to find the solution. I had to call a method that change the whole options object when the buttons are clicked. When I did what you suggested, the datepicker change the min mode but does not change back again when I click in other mode, I don't know why.

Comment: try printing to console your options object, see if you change the `minMode` correctly

Comment: Now I understand what happen. Your solution is right. I thought it was not working because when you select 'year', for exemple, and after 'day', the datepicker will open first in year selection. But now I see that if I select a year, it allow me to select a month and a day. Thank you very much.